# How to do pre jit on coreclr and corefx?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, coreclr

I am making a program to run another program under my frameworks.

I want to hold the pre-launched program and unhold it when actual program begins because launching time speed.

Slightly increase performance after do that but I want some more like using Native Image dll from `crossgen`.
because Native Image is too haevy for my environment. I want to do pre-jit some of dlls or parts of dlls.

I read [this article for pre-jit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31316/Pre-compile-pre-JIT-your-assembly-on-the-fly-or-tr) but coreclr does not have `RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod()` and corefx does not make reference dll for it. `RuntimeHelpers class` in `net standard 1.X` or `netcoreapp1.x` does not has `PrepareMethod()`.

So how I can do pre-jit with coreclr and corefx?